# django-allauth doesn't register social links

Tags: django, django-allauth

Something wrong happened to **django-allauth** when I deployed my site on the hosting. I didn't do anything to django-allauth.

That's what I get on localhost, [django-allauth on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5dUf.jpg) and on hosting 
[django-allauth on hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUcPH.jpg)

What I have done:

1. downloaded my site to gitlab which work on localhost,
2. downloaded it to hosting via `git clone`,
3. build venv, of course.

I just downloaded **django-allauth** on the hosting via `pip install django-allauth`. Without **django-allauth** everything works well.

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://yakhshisarova.ru/

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/realestate/templates/authentication_links.html, error at line 3
   Reverse for 'vk_login' not found. 'vk_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : {% load socialaccount %}
   2 : 
   3 : <a href=" {% provider_login_url 'vk' method='oauth2' %} ">Войти с помощью ВКонтакте</a>
   4 : 

Traceback:

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/realestate/realestate/index/views.py" in index
  15.         'filters_form': filters_form

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  194.                 return template.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  177.                 return self._render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/templatetags/socialaccount.py" in render
  39.         return provider.get_login_url(request, **query)

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/provider.py" in get_login_url
  11.         url = reverse(self.id + "_login")

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  88.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/private/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'vk_login' not found. 'vk_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

*setting.py*

```
"""
Django settings for realestate project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'dfgwe34tfQG%^UJ^&UH,kl/;l898'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yakhshisarova.ru', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'widget_tweaks',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'realestate.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'realestate.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST': HOST,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/httpdocs/static'
```

Why that's happening?

Comment: please be more specific about the problem, exactly what are you doing and how is it going wrong? Also, include relevant errors in the content of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add vk as SocialApp through the django admin first. From the [providers docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#):

> You must add a SocialApp record per provider via the Django admin containing these app credentials.

Comment: @АльбертАлександров could you share your settings.py?

Comment: Added. Please, check.